# How risky is eval() of a data-attribute value in JavaScript? What a malicious user can do in this situation?

Tags: javascript

I've to admit I'm not an expert about `eval` and why [you should never use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval?retiredLocale=it#never_use_eval!).

I'm in a situation were I need to `eval` a small piece of JavaScript string, put in a data-attribute:

```html
<div data-controller="css-prop-mutator"
    data-css-prop-mutator-source-param="detail.scrollRatio"
    data-css-prop-mutator-changer-param="value * 100" <!-- will be eval() -->
</div>
```

Behind that element there is a regular JavaScript class (I don't bother about the framework used here), where I'm using (or want to use) `eval`:

```js
class Controller {
    update(e: CustomEvent) {
        const { value } = e.detail.scrollRatio;
        eval(this.element.dataset.changerParam); // will eval
    }
}
```

So, to the actual question: what kind of malicious attempt may occur?

Comment: So is your actual question: what kind of malicious attempt may occur, or how can you prevent one? Please specify in the body of your post.

Comment: But why do you need that eval to begin with? What on-page or site functionality is this supposed to be used for? (because creating a small math parser based on "is this string data a valid maths expression" is a solved problem, you can already use an off the shelf library for that without ever needing eval)

Comment: @bob.mazzo thanks, I'll update the question

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the developer may "alter" (change) the value using that data-attribute. Eventually, that value (that is coming from an event, NDR), will be the value of a CSS property. I can't restrict to some math.

Comment: Who constitutes "a developer"? Because why generate this kind of HTML when you can generate the exact JS needed on the server side and have a script with src attribute instead? HTML is for the end user, for people who control what gets sent to those users using eval from HTML makes very little sense if you can just generate the necessary JS directly as part of the site build process.

Comment: If `"value * 100"` is part of the delivered HTML there's low risk (that string can also be a JavaScript string literal, and the fact that it comes from an attribute makes no difference). By the way, I would advise you to embrace security as a whole, for example, using only secure HTTPS-only cookies would significantly reduce the risk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it *depends*.

The biggest risk is a XSS Injection attack.

Consider a scenario, your are evaling something that contains the name of a user. What if I was able to write some JS in place of my name. So when my name displays for other users (say in a feed), that JS code gets executed on their browser.

What I can do:

- I can do an API call for stealing their cookies, messages,
  localStorage data.
- I can show a genuine looking popup saying your account has been
  locked, and you need to pay up to unlock it.
- Anything that JS can do.

`eval()` makes your code slow, it also makes debugging hard. Since you are basically executing a string, you won't get a stack trace.

A lot of developers consider it "*evil*". I however feel like it's not a binary choice.

I avoid it personally because I feel like it just adds techincal debt to the code as the codebase grows. You can always do things better without `eval`.

However, it all boils down to how much you trust the input to `eval()`. If you are *not* running `eval()` on a user input and just maybe hardcoding a string that you trust will be 100% safe, and makes your code easy, go for it. But as code base grows, you will face the tech debt.

> Maybe I was unclear in the first place, but I'm try to understand exactly how the user can manipulate that data attribute and do something bad.

It depends on what you put in the data attribute, as in, if your data attribute contains something that directly or indirectly comes from a user input.

If the string inside the data-attribute comes from you, the developer. Say, it might be hardcoded in the HTML or maybe it comes from the server, **and a user input plays no part in it**. Then it's safe to use.

You need to ask yourself this question: *Will a piece of user data or user input ever end up inside my data attribute?*

If no, then you use it. If yes, don't use it.

### Example

---

```js
const usernameInputField = document.getElementById('username');
const renderedUsernameSpan = document.getElementById('rendered-username');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

usernameInputField.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    renderedUsernameSpan.dataset.username = e.target.value;
    renderedUsernameSpan.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    eval(renderedUsernameSpan.dataset.username);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Type something in the username field and it will be set to <code>data-username.</code>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <label for="username">Enter username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username">
</div>
<p>
  <code>data-username value:</code>
  <span id="rendered-username" data-username=""></span>
</p>
<hr>
<button id="button">Click to eval() the data-username</button>
```

Some possible inputs:

1. `43`
2. `innocentUsername=1; alert('hacked');`
3. `window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'`

Comment: Except the last paragraph is never true: you _can't_ trust user input because you don't _control_ user input. The moment this loads in a user's browser, _that browser, computer, and network connection_ are the problem. A piece of malicious code injected into the page can trivially change that data property, without you or the user ever knowing. Which is why eval is almost always locked by disallowing `unsafe-eval` ithrough CSP.

Comment: Thanks for the "general" explanation. Maybe I was unclear in the first place, but I'm try to understand exactly how the user can manipulate that data attribute and do something bad.

Comment: Excellent example. So in this case it would be quite safe!